# Function in C only working when an unrelated line is present

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct card_t{
    char value;
    char suit[50];
} card_t;
card_t draw(){
    card_t karta;
    int v = (rand() % 13)+2;
    int s = (rand() % 4)+1;
    if(v<=9){
        karta.value = v +'0';
    }else{
        if (v==10)
            karta.value='T';
        if (v==11)
            karta.value='J';
        if (v==12)
            karta.value='Q';
        if (v==13)
            karta.value='K';
        if (v==14)
            karta.value='A';
    }
    if (s==1)
        strcpy(karta.suit, "of Spades");
    if (s==2)
        strcpy(karta.suit, "of Hearts");
    if (s==3)
        strcpy(karta.suit, "of Diamonds");
    if (s==4)
        strcpy(karta.suit, "of Clubs");




    return karta;
}
void face_up(card_t deck[],int size){

   for(int i=0;i<=size;i++){
        printf("%c %s\n",deck[i].value ,deck[i].suit);
    }
}
int main()
{
    int size;
    card_t *deck;
    deck = malloc(100*sizeof(char));
    card_t karta;
    karta=draw();
    for (int i=0; i<100 ; i++){

        deck[i]=karta;
        if(strcmp(deck[i].suit,"of Spades")==0 && deck[i].value=='A'){
            size=i;
            break;
        }
        karta=draw();
        /*THIS ONE*/printf("%c %s\n",deck[i].value ,deck[i].suit);
    }
    face_up(deck,size);
    free(deck);
    return 0;
}
```

If I remove the line marked with /*THIS ONE*/ , the function face_up won't print anything , but if the line is there it works. Any ideas ? Tried it several times and its the same thing .
I would get double print if i leave it there , which i dont need.
Im sorry for the bad code / formatting but i am kinda new to this and yeah ...
Thank you for  your help in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line here `deck = malloc(100*sizeof(char));` allocates memory on the heap to store an array of 100 chars. What you want to do, is to allocate an array of 100 card_t. To do this just replace the statement with the following one:

```
deck = malloc(100*sizeof(card_t));
```